# Download a file from internet to AWS S3 using AWS lambda with python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to download a file from the internet to AWS S3 using AWS lambda with python code.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

By using the [Boto3 library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html), you can upload the file to your bucket after downloading it. [Here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) is the boto3 function you need to use.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```